# How to connect USB-to-RS485 adapter to RS485-RJ45 input of an LFP battery BMS?

Tags: usb, rs485, bms, lifepo4, rj45

I have Victron Multi 48/5000 connected to Cerbo GX. Works fine.

Now I need to connect Cerbo GX to the LFP battery, to RS485 (because no CAN input).

```
Cerbo GX <-#1-> USB-to-RS485 <-#2-> RS485-RJ45 (of LiFePO4 battery)
```

How to make 2nd connection? Which pins should I use to connect to the battery?

[image: battery panel]

Links:

- USB-to-RS485 adapter: https://www.waveshare.com/usb-to-rs485.htm
- Battery: https://www.xdbattery.com/512KWH-48V-lifepo4-Rack-Mounted-battery-module-309.html

Comment: Ask for a product manual or data sheet.

Comment: Yeah, requested that. Thx

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, there's no standard pinout for RS-485-over-RJ45. So, you will have to ask the vendor.

Honestly, they should be very happy to supply you with that information: someone who wants to know that is prone to buying more battery racks from them.

Comment: Well, contacted to them. Promised me to provide some info.

Comment: @Kirby glad to hear that!